# What is the purpose of this Javascript object key?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

Consider this function in matter.js:

```
/**
 * Creates a new set of axes from the given vertices.
 * @method fromVertices
 * @param {vertices} vertices
 * @return {axes} A new axes from the given vertices
 */
Axes.fromVertices = function(vertices) {
    var axes = {};

    // find the unique axes, using edge normal gradients
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        var j = (i + 1) % vertices.length,
            normal = Vector.normalise({
                x: vertices[j].y - vertices[i].y,
                y: vertices[i].x - vertices[j].x
            }),
            gradient = (normal.y === 0) ? Infinity : (normal.x / normal.y);

        // limit precision
        gradient = gradient.toFixed(3).toString();
        axes[gradient] = normal;
    }

    return Common.values(axes);
};
```

For completion, here is the Common.values() function:

```
/**
 * Returns the list of values for the given object.
 * @method values
 * @param {} obj
 * @return {array} Array of the objects property values
 */
Common.values = function(obj) {
    var values = [];

    if (Object.keys) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            values.push(obj[keys[i]]);
        }
        return values;
    }

    // avoid hasOwnProperty for performance
    for (var key in obj)
        values.push(obj[key]);
    return values;
};
```

I can't quite figure out the structure of the axes object. I don't see the point of the `axes[gradient] = normal` code since the `Common.values() function` only returns the values and, therefore, the gradient will never be returned?

Comment: If there are two gradients like 0.5671 and 0.5672, they'll produce only one value since the latter replaces the former.

Comment: Looks like it is just basic key/value pairs being used to iterate the objects values.

It will only return a single value at a time. Gradients require more than one value - so you would have to store the start and end values in order to use them to generate the gradient (for each object).

Comment: @Korgrue—why are two values required for a gradient? They're often expressed as percentages and fractions and in the OP: `gradient  = ... (normal.x / normal.y)` so it appears they are decimal fractions (though usually expressed as y/x or rise over run in the systems that I'm familiar with).

Comment: Fraction, percentages, how ever you choose to generate them, they still require a start and end value (color stops) - so, at least two values are necessary to generate a gradient in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `gradient` is never returned, only the `normal` values are. The entire process of stuffing them in that object is to avoid duplication, as the comment explains:

```
// find the unique axes, using edge normal gradients
```

If you have multiple normals with similar (up to three digits) gradients, only the last of them will be returned.